# need to convert iframe to link when responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, hyperlink

I have iframe on my website looks like

```
<iframe class="frame" src="http://www.example.com" width="717" height="553"> </iframe>
```

and i need to convert it to

```
<a class="frame" href="http://www.example.com">VISIT NOW</a>
```

when responsives on smartphones

is there a way to do it?

Comment: Supplying us with a picture of the desired result would be nice. A drawing or anything that can show us the wanted end result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media queries like:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  a.frame {
    display: block;
  }
  iframe.frame {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  a.frame {
    display: none;
  }
  iframe.frame {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

or you can add some classes to your current code if you use bootstrap (this code is for bootstrap 4):

```
<iframe class="frame d-none d-md-block" src="http://www.example.com" width="717" height="553"> </iframe>

<a class="frame d-block d-md-none" href="http://www.example.com">VISIT NOW</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create both iframe & anchor tag . Then give different CSS classes for each of them , use media query to hide and show . You can change media width according to your requirements

```css
.mobile-show {display:none;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width:480px){
       .mobile-hide {display:none;}
       .mobile-show {display:block !important;}
    }
```

```html
    <iframe class="frame mobile-hide" src="http://www.example.com" width="717" height="553"> </iframe>
    <a class="frame mobile-show" href="http://www.example.com">VISIT NOW</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

put your iframe into a div tag like

```
<div id="frameID">
   <iframe class="frame" src="http://www.example.com" width="717" height="553"> </iframe> 
</div>
```

using javaScript you can do something like

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("frameID");
if($(window).width() <= 768) {
element.innerHTML = "<a class='frame' href='http://www.example.com'>VISIT NOW</a>";
}else{
element.innerHTML = "<iframe class='frame' src='http://www.example.com' width='717' height='553'> </iframe>";
}
</script>
```

using css media query

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #frameID a.frame {
    display: block;
  }
  #frameID iframe.frame {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #frameID a.frame {
    display: none;
  }
  #frameID iframe.frame {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

and if you are using bootstrap3

```
<iframe class="frame hidden-xs hidden-sm" src="http://www.example.com" width="717" height="553"> </iframe>
<a class="frame hidden-md hidden-lg" href="http://www.example.com">VISIT NOW</a>
```